# RUST! are items more rust prone in an free standing shed than in my garage?

Tags: insulation, construction, shed, rust

my garage is not heated or cooled but it seems tools dont rust there as much as in my free standing shed.  why is that.

can i simply cover outdoor metal items with a tarp to inhibit large % of rust by not allowing moisture to settle on them at night?

Comment: The temperature swings in the shed are almost certainly much greater than in the larger and likely better protected garage.  The items get colder, then warmer humid air comes in and condensation forms more readily.  A tarp may not help and may actually make things worse by inhibiting air flow.

Comment: What is the shed made of? If it is metal it may condense more moisture on the walls than a wooden shed.

Comment: the shed is made of wood. ....so regarding condensation... when i go out in morniing and see wet surfaces (for example the tops of my plastic garbage bins.... you are saying that is warm morning air landing on cold surfaces chilled overnight?  putting a tarp (theoritically speaking) 1 inch over those surfaces wont make the condensation fall on the tarp rather than form on the plastic surface 1inch below the tarp?

Comment: damp causes rust, coat the exposed metal parts of you tools with fine oil or WD40 before storing them